Android. How to show button above keyboard on bottom sheet dialog?
I'm using BottomSheetDialogFragment with composable content:
   override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                MyTheme {                   
                        MyBottomSheetContent()
                    }
                }
            }
    }

My composable MyBottomSheetContent has title, input text field and button. When the text input field is focused and the keyboard is shown, my button is hidden behind the keyboard. However, I would like it to rise above the keyboard.
I tried to add the following style for the dialog:
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), R.style.MyBottomSheetDialogStyle)
    }

<style name="MyBottomSheetDialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/bottomSheetStyleWrapper</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_light</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    </style>

However this did not help.
I also tried to add an Modifier.imePadding() for the column in which the content of the bottom sheet is located. In this case, my bottom sheet stretches across the entire screen and instead of the dialogue content I see a white screen.
Please tell me what other options there may be to solve my problem?
